# File Writer How to Stop Over Writing text from file

Tags: java, file, overwrite, filewriter

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

public class test3 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {

                //write
                try {
                        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Danny\\Desktop\\Credits.txt");
                        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter (fw);

                        pw.println("This is just some test data");

                        pw.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e){
                        System.out.println("Error!");
                }

                //read
                try {
                        FileReader fr = new FileReader("C:\\Users\\Danny\\Desktop\\Credits.txt");
                        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (fr);

                        String str;

                        while ((str = br.readLine()) != null ) {
                                System.out.println(str + "\n");
                        }
                        br.close();            

                }
                catch (IOException e){
                        System.out.println("File not found!");
                }

        }
}
```

This works but over writes the text file each time with the new input. How do I stop this over writing so that all information is stored in the file like an archive.

Comment: so you want to `append` your file ?

Comment: check the constructor  of `FileWriter` class. `FileWriter(File file, boolean append)`

Answer (score 5):

Pass `true` to your FileWriter like this -

`FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Danny\\Desktop\\Credits.txt",true);`

The second parameter to the FileWriter constructor will tell it to append to the file.

Docs `-->` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter(java.lang.String,boolean)

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in Append mode the next time you want to write to file.

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\Danny\\Desktop\\Credits.txt",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get("yourfile"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8,
    StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```